# Pagination 3 With Room Database Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, pagination, android-room

How can I implement Pagination 3 in Android Studio using Java, on the web there are many examples with Kotlin but none in specific that helps me implement Pagination 3 and that it uses only data obtained from Room Database ... If someone has an example of interest or a useful web reference.